# Sum of integers=sum of their reciprocals

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Given a positive integer $n$ , find all sequences $a_1, a_2,...., a_n$ of integers such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$

.
I checked for small values of n like $1, 2,3,4$ .

$n=1$ , $a_1=1$ , $a_1=-1$

$n=2$ ,  $(1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, 1), (-1, -1)$

and $a_1=a, a_2=-a$

$n=3$

$(1, a, -a), (-1, a, -a)$ and their permutations and $(1, -1, 1), (1, -1, -1),.... $ basically those containing 1 and -1 .

A common pattern occurs for $n=4$ as well

That is either numbers occur in pairs of $(a, -a)$ or belong to $1, -1$ .

So like for $n=4$ one solution would be $(a, -a, b, -b)$ or $(a, -a, 1,-1) $ Hope you get the idea. Is there any way to prove that or even if it's not correct is there any nice to way to find all these sequences

Thanks

Edit: Also including a proof for $n=3$ similar ways also lead to proof for $n=4$ . $n=1, 2$ is trivial.

$\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}=a_1+a_2+a_3$

as if $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ works $(-a_1, -a_2, -a_3)$ also.

So assume $a_1+a_2+a_3 \geq 0$

if $a_1,a_2,a_3 > 0$

then $a_1 \geq \frac{1}{a_1}$ equal only if $a_1=1$ . Similarly doing for other terms we get $(1, 1,1)$

If there is exactly one negative.

Let that be $a_3$

$\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}-\frac{1}{a_3}=a_1+a_2-a_3$ where $a_i$ is in N.

wel$LHS<\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}<=2$

So it must be 1 or 0.If its 1 , we can using inequality get a1=1, a2=b or reverse.
If its 0 then just substitute $a_3=a_1+a_2$ .

If there are two negatives things are similar as well

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: It's my own observation

Comment: Can you give one purely numerical example for a small value to make it clear what you are doing?

Comment: one solution when $n=3$ would be 1+1/3+1/(-3)=1+3+(-3) , or for n=4 would be 1+1/(1)+1/3+1/(-3)=1+1+3-3

Comment: Also The proof given in the edit can also be used to show there are finitely many sequences for any given n

Comment: $\{2,-3,-3,-3,-3,4,4,4,4,-6\}$ Since the two sums are both zero, you can multiply all elements by any non-zero integer to get infinitely many solutions for $n=10$.

Comment: Oh right! I was dumb there

Comment: Actually  , I think that if we get  a single sequences  where no of 1s is not same as no of -1s , we can multiply by some non zero constant to get counter examples. So maybe we would want to show this property when the sum is non zero?

Comment: There are also infinitely many solutions for $n=5$, e.g. integer multiples of $[-40, -3, 5, 8, 30]$.

Comment: Yes the fact the solution was in form (1, a, -a) already creates it

Comment: Ok i think I found  an example when sum is non zero as well, it's when u have 1 2, 9 -3s ans, 20 4s and 9 -6s, in the sequence of a_is

Comment: Though not the op, problem as we found counter examples to the pattern of the solutions which occur for n=1, 2,3,4 . I think it would be interesting to figure out  for what values of n we would have an $a_i$ sequences with no 1 and -1 , and no two distinct terms whose sum is 0. By @RobertIsrael example I think we can find that for all n multiplies of 5 , we have a counter example .

Comment: An example for $n=6$ is $[2,-4, -9, -10, -15, 36]$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael how r u finding them so easily

Comment: @SAYANTANMAZUMDAR A simple search program in Maple.