# Sum of integers =sum of their reciprocals special case

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Problem :- Are there infinitely many integers $x_1, x_2, x_3,..., x_5$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{5} \frac{1}{x_i}=\sum_{i=1}^{5} x_i$ and sum of no two terms in $x_i$ is $0$ and $x_i$ is never $1$ or $-1$ . and $(x_1, x_2,. .., x_5)=1$

The original problem was posted here [Sum of integers=sum of their reciprocals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810811/sum-of-integers-sum-of-their-reciprocals)
. However that problem after the pattern was countered by some people in comments, seemed to have reached a dead end, however I was still wondering whether there are infinitely many solutions , and possibly generalize to more than 5 terms .

I just  tried to make cases on the number of negative terms as in the previous problem .

Edit: As for the generalization part using n=6 solution mentioned in the linked post[comment section] note and $n=5$ we can compose other solutions for example
$\frac{1}{-40k}+\frac{1}{-3k}+\frac{1}{5k}+\frac{1}{8k}+\frac{1}{30k}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{-4}+\frac{1}{-9}+\frac{1}{-10}+\frac{1}{-15}+\frac{1}{36}$ would be a valid construction for $n=11$ under certain infinitely many values of $k$ to make sure no two terms sum to 0. and as we paste another $\frac{1}{-40a}+\frac{1}{-3a}+\frac{1}{5a}+\frac{1}{8a}+\frac{1}{30a}$
and so $\frac{1}{-40a}+\frac{1}{-3a}+\frac{1}{5a}+\frac{1}{8a}+\frac{1}{30a}+\frac{1}{-40k}+\frac{1}{-3k}+\frac{1}{5k}+\frac{1}{8k}+\frac{1}{30k}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{-4}+\frac{1}{-9}+\frac{1}{-10}+\frac{1}{-15}+\frac{1}{36}$ would become valid example for $n=16$ and in general we have construction for $n=5k+1$ we can similarly paste the 6 term solution again and again along with the 5 term solution and get a solution for $n=5a+6b$ by Mc Chicken nugget theorom https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem . All $n \geq 20$ can be written in that form so we now have infinite solutions for them [note again we have restrictions on constants we are multiplying with to make sure no two sum to $0$[gcd is always obeyed as we can have two coprime terms in the sequence always],but even with that we have infinite].

there are some other ways to compose solutions for $n=31$ using only $n=5$ manually without writing code by which we have examples for $n \geq 120$ using same method.

This is the method we know

$1+\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{-3}+\frac{1}{-40}=1+30+8+5-3-40=1$ Square both sides without grouping that is for example dont write $a+a=2a$ and keep it as $a$ and $a$ and separetely in the new sequence we have $6^2=36$ terms only two terms that will cancel[sum to 0] will be those in pairs of [observe in the expansion we again have sum of integers=sum of reciprocals] of $8*5$ and $-40*1$ , as we didnt group total 4 terms got removed , and no two other terms sum to 0 , also remove the $1^2$ from both sides , u are left with $36-4-1=31$ terms and gcd is 1 as one as $5^2$ and $8^2$ were in expansion and they are coprime. Hope i was clear coz this part was a bit tough for me to write ask on comments for any quiries.

Imma also share a list of solutions that got produced when i coded for $n=5$[the sum of terms being 0 is not a coincidence but forced to make the search program faster]

[image]

some solutions are permutations of others.

Update:
Have a proof for  n=9 .

Take any tuple $(x, y, z)$ sum of no two terms is 0 of integers none is $1$ or $-1$ .

And $x+y+z=0$ .

Take another such tuple $(a, b, c)$

We show infinite solutions for when the sum is $0$ .

hence it suffices to find infinite rational solutions[which are not just created by multipltying one solution with a constant ] as the equation is homogenous .

Now consider

$(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z})(a+b+c)=(x+y+z)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})=0$

When u expand left side u get some sum of rational numbers  u have exactly $3^2=9$ terms take the lcm we have something like [rational numbers produced on expansion of RHS are reciprocals of LHS]

$q(\frac{1}{a1}+.... +\frac{1}{a_9})=(a_1+a_2+.... +a_9)\frac{1}{q}=0$

That implies

$\frac{1}{a_1}+... +\frac{1}{a_9}=a_1+a_2+.... +a_9$

We can add further conditions on $(x, y, z)$ and $(a, b, c)$ To ensure no two sum to 0 and gcd=1 and no term is 1 or -1 but those are easy to ensure maintaining infinite solutions .

Previously had posted this as an answer,if i wasent clear enough in it
as it got one downvote . Then here is a example to illustrate better

take $(x,y,z)=(3,4,-7)$ and $(a,b,c)=(3,5,-8)$

$0=(3+4-7)(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{8})=1+3/5-3/8+4/3+4/5-4/8-7/3-7/5+7/8$

and $0=(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{7})(3+5-8)=1+\frac{5}{3}-\frac{8}{3}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{5}{4}-\frac{8}{4}-\frac{3}{7}-\frac{5}{7}+\frac{8}{7}$

as $1=120/120$,$3/5=(24*3)/120$ similarly simplify other terms

U get

$\frac{120+24*3-15*3+4*8*5+4*8*3-40*7-4*15-7*24+7*15}{120}=120(1/(120)+1/(24*3)-1/(15*3)+1/(4*8*5)+1/(4*8*3)-1/(40*7)-1/(4*15)-1/(7*24)+1/(7*15))=0$

Automatically giving solution $[120,24*3,-15*3,4*8*5,4*8*3,-40*7,-4*15,-7*24,7*15]$ U can verify no two sum to 0.

More update:-

After some work i showed infinite solutions for $n=7$ and infinite soluitions to the orginal problem but rather the condition that

$(\sum_{i=1}^{5} x_i)/(\sum_{i=1}^{5} \frac{1}{x_i})$ is a non zero perfect square

Comment: Ah, since Robert gave a solution with 5 terms, I misread your approach as finding solutions for many terms.  The proof for finitely many solutions should(?) be pretty direct, let me have a think about it.

Comment: My intuition was actually thinking it has infinitely many

Comment: Robert gave infinitely many solutions with $n = 5$, so what is it that you're asking in the problem as stated?

Comment: @CalvinLin It doesn't satisfy the gcd condition

Comment: I also had this other idea that maybe in roberts example 8*5=40 is no coincidence, as -40 is in solution and maybe we would like to replace $x_3$ by $-x_1x_2$ . Then the expression can be simplifed as $(a-1)(b-1)(\frac{1}{ab}-1)=(c+d)(1-\frac{1}{cd})$ , both the terms look kind of similar .

Comment: I tried to set c+d=-(a-1)(b-1) and cd=ab, so ((a-1)(b-1))^2-4ab is perfect square we write in terms of b-1 so $((a-1)x)^2-4x-4a$ is perfect square would work

Comment: Also like its not only squaring u can multiply two solutions to get another or add two solutions thats what i am basically doing in the edit section

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, since there is a solution $x=[x_1,\cdots,x_5]$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i =0  $, $x=[3,40,-5,-30,-8]$. Other solutions can be obtained as $x=k[3,40,-5,-30,-8]$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: @Ragno but (x1, x2,..., x5)  is not 1 in that case

Comment: Or like even if we don't get gcd 1 solutions can we even get solutions with gcd>1.but they are not created by multiply a constant with a previous solution